# How to get absolute path from a relative url with no outside info?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I'm trying to dynamically determine whether I'm on a certain page, and set a style on any link linking to itself (for a navigation menu).

The part that's catching me up is how to determine that the page is the current page.

I know I can get window.location, and compare it to the href of any links, but there tiered folders, some of which have files named the same way, and I can't rely on setting a base server url.

Basically I need the value that you get when you hover your mouse over a link, with all the relativity of the href attribute applied to the current location. I'm not really sure how to do that, though.

Comment: could you provide some examples? i'm still not sure what you want exactly.

Answer (score 4):

This one works best cross browser

```
//Resolve absolute url's from relative ones
function qualifyURL( url ){
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = url; // set string url
  url = img.src; // get qualified url
  img.src = null; // no server request
  return url;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this. This one works but it will generate a lot of traffic if you try to run it several times in the same page.

Comment: that's why img.src = null is done, prevents a server request from being made

Comment: This one doesn't seem to be working with Chrome 22. There's no way to stop the GET request from being made.

Answer (score 4):

based on drew's answer, i tested this

```
function resolveUrl( url ){
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href=url; // set string url
  url = a.href; // get qualified url
  return url;
}
```

and it seems to work for ie8 and up. ie7 doesnt resolve anything.

*-pike

Comment: Works better than the `img` tag for newer versions of Chrome. It doesn't send a '/null' request to the server.